# In php how do you log errors but do not display them to user

Tags: php, error-handling

I have the following code to control my error reporting. I'm trying to make it so I can tail the error logs in our server, but I do not want any errors to be displayed on the page. I am not trying to simply make errors go away, we do not have any currently.

```
   if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
            ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');

        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your code is do the job.

Comment: I thought so too but it seems that we are not logging errors with this code. Possibly it is somewhere else?

Comment: oh yes, just remove `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: That just displayed the errors again.

Answer (score 6):

Use a file log

```
case 'development':
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
    ini_set("log_errors", 1);
    ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
break;


error_log( "Hello, errors!" );
```